# Dgrid: Same row height for across multiple ColumnSets

Tags: css, dojo, dgrid

Is it possible to automatically have the same height in all columns when using ColumnSets (without specifying the height manually)?

```
new table({
    store: store,
    columnSets: [
        [
            [colA]
        ],
        [
            [colB]
        ]
    ]
}, "grid1");
```

If all the columns are within the same ColumnSet there is no problem.

```
new table({
    store: store,
    columnSets: [
        [
            [colA, colB]
        ]
    ]
}, "grid2");
```

Please take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dawp21Ly/

Comment: Does that fare any better with dgrid 0.4.0?  That fiddle is using 0.3.1.

Comment: It is the same with dgrid 0.4.0.I just wasn't able to find a public require for that version.

Comment: For future reference, https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/10/15/dojo-faq-how-to-use-jsfiddle-to-provide-a-functioning-test-case/ provides an example of how to set up any dgrid/etc. versions in JSFiddle.